# Does Rose appear in future episodes of Doctor Who or Torchwood?

Tags: doctor-who

At the end of season 2 during the stint of he 10th Doctor played by David Tennent, Rose (Billie Piper) is left behind in a parallel universe, ending her character's arc on the series. She suggests at the end of the episode that she will seek out that world's parallel Torchwood and join it. This leaves her character open to recurring in either series... Does she?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, in Series 4 of Doctor Who and in the upcoming 50th anniversary special. She also has a small cameo in the Doctor Who episode "The End Of Time (Part 2)".

Comment: and there are [rumours](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/tvshowbiz/article-2301561/David-Tennant-Billie-Piper-confirmed-return-Doctor-Who-50th-anniversary-special.html) about Rose, as well as Ten, returning for the 50th anniversary show.

Comment: Those rumors have recently been confirmed, and David has been seen on the filming set.

Comment: Woo Hoo! My favorite companion! (So far, I'm in season 3 of DW and 1 of TW. Hope Billie Piper and Chris Eccelstien both come round again.

Answer (score 5):

OK so you're talking about Doomsday, this is what happens in order. These are physical appearances of Rose Tyler:

1. *Turn Left*, where she helps Donna change the events back to normal.
2. *The Stolen Earth*, where she helps everyone save the Doctor and then
   the Meta-Crisis occurs in which the half-Doctor goes and stays with
   Rose in the parallel universe.
3. The Moment uses Rose Tyler's form to talk to the Doctor in *The Day of The Doctor*.

Answer (score 3):

In the 50th anniversary, Billie Piper showed up as the consciousness of the Moment. She was not, in fact, Rose Tyler, but she told the War Doctor (the one in between Paul McGann and Christopher Eccleston) that she was from his future, and her appearance was definitely linked to Rose. She called herself "Bad Wolf".

Comment: The Moment even says "My name's Rose. Rose Tyler", before correcting itself that's not the case in this form.

Answer (score 3):

**Rose has appeared in some form in two subsequent arcs.**

- She appears in multiple episodes of series 4 (David Tennant and Catherine Tate).  Throughout this series, there are:

  > Brief flashes of Rose on screens, calling out to the Doctor, but he’s always looking away.  This is the series equivalent of “Bad Wolf”.

  In the episode *Turn Left*,

  > Rose has a bigger role. When Donna alters her timeline, Rose helps her return events to normal, and gives hints about the ominous big bad coming in the finale.

  And the series finale, we see

  > Rose, Mickey and Jackie. Davros’s reality bomb, has broken down the barriers between parallel universes. This has allowed Rose to come back to the reality with her Doctor.
- In the fiftieth anniversary episode, *The Day of the Doctor*, we get a form of Rose.

  > The Moment, a sentient bomb, takes the form of Bad Wolf Rose as an “interface” for the Doctor. It recognises Rose as a familiar face from the Doctor’s past.
- Rose has never appeared in an episode of Torchwood, or indeed any other spin-off series, after the events of *Doomsday*.